# Can't properly access array using another class

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get the values of **outputArray** that were initialized in the class **LightsOutPuzzle** in my class, solve. But after printing the elements of the array

1) before calling the class solve in **LightsOutPuzzle** 
 2) after calling solve, the elements are not equal, it's as if it has been initialized again.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LightsOutPuzzle extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JFrame f;
    public JPanel p1;
    public JPanel p2;
    public JButton[] buttonArray;
    public JButton solve;
    public int nRows = 5;
    public int nColumns = 5;
    public int nTotalButtons = nRows * nColumns;
    public int[] outputArray = new int[25];

    public void create() {
        init();
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
        f = new JFrame("Lights Out Puzzle");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p2 = new JPanel();

        solve = new JButton("Solve");

        p2.add(solve);

        f.add(p1);
        f.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        solve.addActionListener(new Action());
    }

    public void init() {    
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(nRows, nColumns, 0, 0));

        int[] inputArray = new int[25];
        int i=0;

        buttonArray = new JButton[nTotalButtons];
        for (int nNum = 0; nNum < nTotalButtons; nNum++) 
        {
            buttonArray[nNum] = new JButton("");
            add(buttonArray[nNum]);
            //clickability
            buttonArray[nNum].addActionListener(this);
            buttonArray[nNum].setBackground(Color.yellow);
            buttonArray[nNum].setActionCommand("" + nNum);
        }

        //reading config file
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
               while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                    inputArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString());
                    i++;
               }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //drawing text input
        for(i=0; i<nTotalButtons; i++){
            if(inputArray[i] == 1)
                buttonArray[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            p1.add(buttonArray[i]);
        }
    }

    public void save() {
        int i = 0;      
        for (i=0; i<25; i++) {
            if(buttonArray[i].getBackground() == Color.yellow)
                outputArray[i] = 1;
            else 
                outputArray[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        //conditions for the puzzle
    }

    public class Action implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            int i;

            save();
            for(i=0; i<25; i++)
                System.out.println(outputArray[i]);
            new solve();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LightsOutPuzzle lop = new LightsOutPuzzle();
        lop.create();
    }
}
```

At this point, all the elements of **outputArray** are equal to 1. However, when I print them using the other class, solve, all the elements of **outputArray** are now equal to 0.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class solve extends LightsOutPuzzle {
private JFrame f;
private JPanel p1;

int[] inputArray = new int[25];
int[] zeroArray = new int[25];
int[] UIState = new int[25];
int[] boardState = new int[25];
Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<int[]>();

public solve() {
    gui();
    init();
}

public void gui() {
    f = new JFrame("Solution");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(nRows, nColumns, 0, 0));

    buttonArray = new JButton[nTotalButtons];
    for (int nNum = 0; nNum < nTotalButtons; nNum++) {
        buttonArray[nNum] = new JButton("");
        add(buttonArray[nNum]);
        //buttonArray[nNum].setBackground(Color.white);
        buttonArray[nNum].setActionCommand("" + nNum);
        p1.add(buttonArray[nNum]);
    }

    f.add(p1);
}

public void init() {
    //drawing text input
    int i;
        for(i=0; i<25; i++)
            System.out.println(outputArray[i]);
    for(i=0; i<nTotalButtons; i++){
        if(outputArray[i] == 1)
            buttonArray[i].setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}

}
```

I would also appreciate tips about proper programming practices in Java. It's been a long time since I coded in this language so I just tried to create a program from what I can remember..

Comment: Tip #1: [SSCCE = Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable that you base your decision on (the color of your buttons) gets reset because you are re-creating the buttons in the `gui` method which gets called from `solve`. As a result, your initial 1's turn to 0's again and that's what is printed during `init`.

Big tip: Don't use GUI properties for your core logic.

Answer (score 1):

Even though class `solve` extends `LightsOutPuzzle`, it is a different object and so has its own copy of `outputArray`.   In the first part of the code you are printing the `outputArray` instance in `LightsOutPuzzle` which has been initialized to ones:

**ActionListener in LightsOutPuzzle**

```
    public class Action implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            int i;

            save();
            for(i=0; i<25; i++)
                    {
                      /////////////PRINTS OUT outputArray IN LightsOutPuzzle
                      System.out.println(outputArray[i]);
                    }

                    ////CREATES NEW solve OBJECT WITH ITS OWN outputArray COPY
                    new solve();
        }
    }
```

Then when you call the `solve` constructor, you are printing the `solve` copy which has not been initialized yet and are all zeros:

**Init method in solve class**

```
public void init() {
    //drawing text input
    int i;
        for(i=0; i<25; i++)
                     {
                         //////PRINTS OUT outputArray IN solve CLASS
                         System.out.println(outputArray[i]);
                     }
                     for(i=0; i<nTotalButtons; i++){
                        if(outputArray[i] == 1)
                           buttonArray[i].setBackground(Color.yellow);
                      }
      }
```

Comment: They're different? Then how can I access the one in LightsOutPuzzle?

Comment: I'm not sure what your intent was for subclassing LightsOutPuzzle in the solve class, since you should subclass to share behavior between classes and you're not doing that. I think you are subclassing to share state, but state is not automatically shared among different copies of the same class or subclasses.  At a glance, don't subclass LightsOutPuzzle, and pass the LightsOutPuzzle state (just outputArray if that's all you care about) to the solve constructor.  One more tip - follow Java coding conventions and CamelCase class names.  So class `solve` should be `Solve`.

Comment: Got it. But what is the simplest way to pass outputArray to the class Solve?

Comment: Simplest way is probably to create a `Solve` constructor that accepts an int[] and then set `Solve's` version of outputArray to the value passed in the constuctor.